# Is there any API for GCP Pricing Calculator for https://cloud.google.com/compute/all-pricing?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

How to calculate the price of Instances and disks which gives the cost according to machine type.

I found [this](https://cloudpricingcalculator.appspot.com/static/data/pricelist.json).
Is this API is from GCP official documentation?
Or is there any other way to get Pricing data from GCP

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look of the official [Google Cloud Platform price emulator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/). There you can get a precise pricing for your personal setup. There is not a public API for this but you can get the pricing list as a JSON file using [this link](https://cloudpricingcalculator.appspot.com/static/data/pricelist.json) that you previously mentioned, since it is an official price list, and is currently receiving updates

Comment: How to implement this using REST API or is there any sdk available?

Comment: There is not a public API for this tool. There is an API to manage your GCP billing, you can take a look in the [Cloud Billing API](https://cloud.google.com/billing/reference/rest/) documentation

Comment: That's Billing, He needs pricing

Comment: https://cloudpricingcalculator.appspot.com/static/data/pricelist.json  is this official?

Comment: Yes, it is official

Comment: but it doesn't contain any information regarding OS i.e price according to OS

Comment: compute engine price may varry if I select different operating systems(windows,RHEL,.. etc) and network, disk, etc.

Is there any API available for fetching/calculating compute engine price based on parameters (operating system, network, disk, zone etc.) by applying different permutations like?

http://cloud.google.com/compute?os=rhel         and     
http://cloud.google.com/compute?os=rhel&memory=13gb&zone=east

Comment: @SaurabhDhage in the [Price emulator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/) you can select from the proivded OS list and see the specific pricing. That is the official tool to calculate the price of a setup. There is not an official API for this

Comment: @ChristianGonzalez  While analyzing the response of Cloud Billing API for Compute Engine, I observed that there is no exact parameter from which we could identify the machine type(N1Standard 4, NIHighmem 16 etc) except description.

Other than parsing the description, is there any workaround to directly get the SKU object with the particular machine type?

Comment: Checking today (July 20 2020), https://cloudpricingcalculator.appspot.com/static/data/pricelist.json gives a JSON file with the comment "This JSON data is obsolete. Please use https://cloud.google.com/billing/v1/how-tos/catalog-api instead."